# How to download a file to a specific folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, webclient

I want to download a file to a specific folder. I'm using `WebClient.DownloadFile`, but what I would like is to let the user select where this file would be saved, not just download it into any folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: The exact answer is going to depend on which .NET flavor you're using for UI (WPF, Windows Forms, Silverlight, ASP.NET, etc.)

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET. Just edited my question

Comment: You would want to populate a TreeView control and let the user select where they want to upload the file to.  There are commercial components out there that do this really well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder that the user would download the file to would depend on their browser, and system settings.

All you can do is provide the file to download, and it would be up to them (and their browser) to select a local folder (on their system).

If you want to control that process, you would have to use an embedded plugin like Java, Silverlight, Flash, etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Windows Forms, you can use the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) class to allow the users to pick a file name, and then pass that name to the second parameter of [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx).